# How to check if a line has the right syntax like this?

Tags: bash, shell

if i have the following line syntax

```
FirstName, FamilyName, Address, PhoneNo
```

and i am reading a data file that contain information, how can i check that i reads a line with the right syntax ??

**UPDATE::**

i mean a function i send to it each line (from a while loop), and its return 0 if the line is correct and 1 if the line is not ?

**UPDATE2::**

the correct form is

```
first name(string), last name(string), address(string),  phone no.(string)
```

**so if the line is missing one or if there more than 4,, it should return a 1,,**

**Using Bash,**

Good Input is ::

```
Rami, Jarrar, Jenin - Wadi berqen, 111 111
```

**# Some Cases To Deal With**

```
, Jarrar, Jenin - Wadi berqen, 111 111

- Extra Spaces::
Rami,    Jarrar, Jenin - Wadi berqen, 111 111

Rami, Jarrar, Jenin - Wadi berqen, 111 111, 213 3123
```

**ALSO ANOTHER UPDATE :)**

```
check(){
x=$(echo "$@" | grep -q '^[^,]\+,[^,]\+,[^,]\+,[^,]\+$')
return $x
}

len=#number of lines in the file
i=1
while [ $i -le $len ]; do
line=$(cat $file)

#------this is where i call the func-----
check $line
if [ $? -eq 1 ];then
echo "ERROR"
else
echo "Good Line"
fi
```

**BASH 2.3.39**
**GREP 2.5.3**

**UPDATE**
now if i make the correct format like this ::

```
string, value, value, value
```

value : is a positive integer

what this line should be replaced ::

```
x=$(echo "$@" | grep -q '^[^,]\+,[^,]\+,[^,]\+,[^,]\+$')
```

??

Comment: If you don't define what a "correct" line is, the question is impossible to answer. Anything with 3 commas is correct? do you validate digits/length for phones?

Comment: Setting the value of x is getting the output to stdout of the command, not the return code. Either use `check () { echo ... | grep ...; }` as Sorpigal suggested in a comment below or use `return $?` instead of `return $x`. The variable `$x` will always be null (and thus 0 when `return` returns it) because of the `-q` option to `grep`.

Comment: By the way "format" is probably a better word in this context than "syntax".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allows empty fields:

```
check () { echo "$@" | grep -q '^[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*$'; }
```

Does not allow any field to be empty:

```
check () { echo "$@" | grep -q '^[^,]\+,[^,]\+,[^,]\+,[^,]\+$'; }
```

Bourne shell without using external utilities (allows empty fields):

```
check () { local IFS=,; set -- $@; return $(test -n "$4" -a -z "$5"); }
```

Bash 3.2 or greater (allows empty fields):

```
check () { [[ $@ =~ ^[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*$ ]]; }
```

Bash 3.2 or greater (does not allow empty fields):

```
check () { [[ $@ =~ ^[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+$ ]]; }
```

Comment: in the second one,, if i omit the first name ,, so if the line is :
last name(string), address(string), phone no.(string)
it return 0,, !!!

Comment: @Rami Jarrar: Did you try it after I fixed it (changed `$1` to `$@`)?

Comment: yeah,, the same result it just return a 0 ,,

Comment: @Rami Jarrar: I get a 1 for each of these: `check ",last,address,phone"; echo $?`, `check , last , address, phone; echo $?`, `string=", last, address, phone"; check $string; echo $?; check "$string"; echo $?`. If I add "first" before the first comma in each one, I get a 0. How are you calling the function and how are you checking the return value? What version of Bash and what version of `grep`?

Comment: For grep grep case I would have simply said `check () { grep -q '^[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*$' <<< "$@" ; }` to avoid the ugliness of the echo/subshell combo. Or, more portably, `check () { echo $@ | grep -q '^[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*$' ; }` works too.

Comment: @Sorpigal: Thanks, the `return` in my function is redundant. I'll remove it. I wrote it without the `<<<` since the OP didn't originally specify Bash.

Comment: ok, now how to check if its like this ::
string, value, value, value

Comment: @Rami Jarrar: You should probably post that as a new question and specify what you mean by value - positive integer, positive or negative integer (allowing + or not), fixed decimal, float, etc., and whether you want to validate within a range. For the most simplistic (positive integer with no sign), change `[^,]` to `[0-9]` for each appropriate field.

Comment: but [0-9] doesn't work :: echo "$@" | grep -q '^[^,]\+,[0-9]\+,[0-9]\+,[0-9]\+$';

Comment: `check () { echo "$@" | grep -q '^[^,]\+,[0-9]\+,[0-9]\+,[0-9]\+$'; }; check "abc,123,234,345"; echo $?; check "abc,def,234,345"; echo $?` gives me a "0" and a "1". How exactly is it that it doesn't work?

Comment: try it with space before each value ??

Comment: @Rami Jarrar: Try `check () { echo "$@" | grep -q '^[^,]\+, *[0-9]\+ *, *[0-9]\+ *, *[0-9]\+ *$'; }`. That will allow spaces before or after the number.

Comment: yea,, now it all works ,, thanks man :),, this is called by regular expressions ,, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
is_correct () {
    grep -q '^[^ ][^,]\+, [^ ][^,]\+, [^ ][^,]\+, [^ ][^,]\+$' <<< "$@"
}
l=0
while read line ; do
    is_correct "$line" && echo line $l ok || echo Invalid syntax on line $l
    ((l+=1))
done <<<"Rami, Jarrar, Jenin - Wadi berqen, 111 111
, Jarrar, Jenin - Wadi berqen, 111 111
- Extra Spaces::
Rami,    Jarrar, Jenin - Wadi berqen, 111 111
Rami, Jarrar, Jenin - Wadi berqen, 111 111, 213 3123
A line, containg fields with, many spaces, but otherwise valid
a, b, c, d
aa, bb, cc, dd"
```

Yields:

```
line 0 ok
Invalid syntax on line 1
Invalid syntax on line 2
Invalid syntax on line 3
Invalid syntax on line 4
line 5 ok
Invalid syntax on line 6
line 7 ok
```

Correctly throws out the all but the sample good line, including the "too many spaces" case. The only place where it fails is if a field has only one character in it.